Usercard expansion does not work
Just found that the usercard expansion looks broken in Chrome. See the animation below:



Only some kind of blinking in the top left corner of the user icon instead of showing a usercard.
Works as expected if I switch the focus (activate) to another application.
Windows 11, Google Chrome
Version 124.0.6367.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Yep, I can confirm the same thing in Mac OS 14.4.1, Firefox 124.0.1. Specifically, it seems like the usercard starts to expand, but then that immediately causes it to revert to normal (and that process continually repeats as long as my mouse is over the profile picture). I'm guessing something about the expanded state of the usercard is causing the site to think I'm no longer hovering over the profile picture, so it reverts.

As this video shows a <div class="esc-remove magic-popup"> with absolute positioning is inserted before the <div class="user-details"> - for a very small amount of time .

It seems that someone in charge of the front end forgot to have coffee this morning.

Probably related, tag popup also broken, it does appear, but disappear when hovering away from the tag, including to the popup itself, making it impossible to Watch or Ignore the tag from it. I'll start a separate bug report for that.

And... done. :)


It seems that someone in charge of the front end forgot to have coffee this morning.

This would've been me. I'm sorry for the mess. I introduced a sweeping but innocent-looking change that included tweaks to our client-side hover event handling code yesterday. That caused a couple of related problems that went unnoticed until it hit production. It's always the innocent ones that give you a false sense of confidence.
The tag popover not showing up properly is caused by the same change. Same for the simultaneous timestamp issue in the post timeline. And of course the user card expansion in our review queues.
A fix for all of these is on its way out to production. I'll make sure to stay properly caffeinated this time.

I had Smokey make you some coffee: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9832682#9832682

The most honest, funny, and sincere answer I saw in a long while, thanks for that. While I won't ask you to make more bugs so I get more such answers, I do hope others will follow your lead! :-)
